What is the physical meaning of the counterterms we add in Lagrangians?
I have a probably very silly question. Please help me with it:
Say we consider the QCD Lagrangian. All of it's terms involve various fields. Now this Lagrangian can simply be called the Lagrangian of a classical theory. But after loop-level diagrams are considered, it becomes a quantum theory, and we see infinities arise and we cancel them with counter terms. My question is that are these counterterms nothing but the fluctuations of the quantum fields present in the Lagrangian. This is because if we start from the beginning with the classical Lagrangian and we at this stage itself start accounting for quantum effects we'd not write just the classical field, but instead write the field expression alongside a varying (whose magnitude can be small or even infinity) variance (standard deviation). Both these methods result in similar expressions.
Edit: I want to add this extra part to the question following the given answer.
Can we hand wavingly say that the counter terms of the part 1 of the answer (the $Z_{\phi}$ 's, not the whole counter terms) are infact the magnitudes of the fluctuations of the field terms whose divergences they cancel?

You tagged renormalization, did you check the relevant sections in textbooks on QFT? Just curious if you saw those as that's an important part of any answers addressing his.

I have seen some references and studied in college but there's never a mention of a relation between the two.

Interesting because normally they show that the lagrangian gains additional pieces due to the renormalization.

@Triatticus, Renormalisation has to be done because of loop divergences. And loop divergences are ultimately high momentum values (fluctuations).                                                So can these additional pieces (that you mentioned) be interpreted as relevant fluctuations in the field values?

I will of course leave his for someone else to answer but the processes are related, I was looking for similar questions as I've seen related ones on here before.

"What is the meaning of the counterterms"? Let's say you are just married and suddenly there are a bevy of shady in-laws popping out from nowhere. You are like "what is going on? did I invite you? why are you here?".  That's the meaning of counterterms.

There are two answers to this depending on what you mean. Based on your question it seems both levels of understanding would be useful. The second answer actually has more of a "physical meaning".
Simple case
Suppose you have a scalar field lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{6}g\varphi^3$$
If you go try to evaluate Feynman Diagrams for this you will encounter 2 problems:

There is no way to enforce our normalization condition $\langle 0|\varphi|0\rangle=0$, as is.
As noted, there are diagrams with divergent momentum integrals.

What can we do to remedy this? For problem 1, we can add the counterterm $Y\varphi$ which will cancel out all the diagrams with a single source to recover this normalization condition. So "physically", we are removing some processes from the Lagrangian.
Problem 2. has a much easier solution (from the point of view of your question). All the Z-factor counterterms were actually always there. I.e. the Lagrangian was actually
$$\mathcal{L} = -Z_\varphi\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}Z_m m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{6}Z_gg\varphi^3+Y\varphi$$ It was just split up like this:
$$\mathcal{L} =-\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{6}g\varphi^3 -\frac{1}{2}(Z_\varphi-1)\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}(Z_m -1) m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{6}(Z_g-1)g\varphi^3+Y\varphi$$
where then the so called "added counter terms" are  $$\mathcal{L}_{ct} = -\frac{1}{2}(Z_\varphi-1)\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}(Z_m -1) m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{6}(Z_g-1)g\varphi^3+Y\varphi$$
Textbooks generally don't really make this fact super explitcit (which I also don't think they actually technically omit it altogether). So the conclusion is, we didn't add these Z counter terms, they were always there. This very possibly may not have been your question, not sure.
More interesting case: Kinetic mixing
Suppose you have a Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}Z_A\partial^\mu A\partial_\mu A-\frac{1}{2}Z_{m_A} m_A^2A^2-\frac{1}{2}Z_B\partial^\mu B\partial_\mu B-\frac{1}{2}Z_{m_B} m_B^2B^2+\frac{1}{2}Z_ggA^2B+\frac{1}{2}Z_h hAB^2+YA+YB$$
specifically in 6 spacetime dimensions. As we can see, we have a vertex that connects two A propagators to a B propagator and vice versa. However, if you draw the 1-loop diagram with 3 A external propagators you will notice that you need to add a term $A^3$ to the lagrangian with its $Z$ factor. Otherwise you can't cancel the divergence from the loop diagram. Similary, you need a $B^3$ term. So here, there is somewhat of a more physical meaning: you now have new processes that are allowed (were they always there?). Adding these latest terms requires you to add another term to cancel out these new divergences, $\partial^\mu A\partial_\mu B$, so a kinetic term with both fields and also an $AB$ term. This new kinetic term is mixing the 2 fields now.

I understand this answer. This is the physical meaning of adding counter terms. In addition, can we hand wavingly say that these counter terms of the part 1 of your answer (the $Z_{\phi}$ 's, not the whole counter terms) are infact the magnitudes of the fluctuations of the field terms whose divergences they cancel?

I can’t really come up with a source that refers to the $Z$ factors like you do here. So in short, i dont know.  Everything I said is out of Srednicki Ch.9 and the renomalization to all orders chapter (19?).

Okay, I got it... I'll think and read more about this. Thanks a lot for the help! :)
